# The most general way to write flat space metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

What is the most general way to write flat space (in d=4 in particular), but still preserving some isometries? In particular I'm interested in the case with 2 isometries, basically by using explicitly only 2/4 coordinates in my metric.

Some examples. We all love to write flat space as:

$$ds_{flat}^2=-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$

But of course with a change of coordinates to spherical. I can write:

$$ds_{flat}^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2 (d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2)$$

with the usual range for the coordinates. A less trivial example with oblate spheroidal coordinates:

$$ds_{flat}^2=  -dt^2+{ \rho^2+L^2 \cos^2\vartheta \over \rho^2+L^2}  d\rho^2+  ( \rho^2+L^2 \cos^2\vartheta  ) d\vartheta^2+ (\rho^2+L^2) \sin^2\vartheta  d\varphi^2  $$

for some constant $L$.

The generic ansatz for flat space would be something like $g_{\mu \nu}=g_{\mu \nu}(x_1,x_2)$ in some ${x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4}$ coordinates. References are welcome.

Comment: Since flat means that the Riemann tensor vanishes, the most general form should be any solution of $R_{\mu\nu\sigma\rho} = 0$, which is a system of PDE:s for the $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question...how are polar coordinates and more "general" than Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Robin: you are right of course, but I want something more explicit! I was hoping that it was already present in literature

Comment: ocelot: I mean a metric parametrized with some unknown function of only two variables, but satisfying some constraints.

Comment: You can choose whatever coordinates you like, and the metric will transform according to the coordinates you choose. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, or what you mean by "preserving isometries" - changing the coordinates does not change anything about the available isometries.

Comment: Yes, in that case is easy. But my approach is the opposite one. Without computing invariants, i want to look at the metric and say that is flat, because I know that this metric is included in the anstatz that I'm seeking. By 2 isometries I mean that only two variables appear explicitly.

Comment: Your trial metric will be flat if there is a coordinate transformation that maps it to the Minkwski metric i.e. starting with the Minkowski metric you arrive at your trial metric courtesy of a coordinate transformation. I don't think there is any easy way to tell this is the case.

Comment: Dear Rexcirus: I've just been browsing your blogs and I realize now that my answer is way too low level for you, so sorry about that. I'll leave it there for now in the hope it might be useful to someone.  I have not see an explicit calculation of how the ansatz looks, and aside from shoving any parameterized ansatz into the curvature tensor definition and brute force hoping this will yield solutions for families of parameters on equating $R=0$, I, like John, don't believe there is a simpler way. You might try physics overflow, as someone may have seen something like .....

Comment: .... this as a step in a research paper. I'd also rewrite your question to make it clear that you understand the principles: you simply want to see examples of where this is done in the literature. Tag your question. Also take a look at the resource request and specific reference tags if you've not seen these before. Also, your word "invariants" is a little unclear in your comment. Do you mean a tensor, or some co-ordinate independent property thereof, by "invariant"; this would explain why you don't seem to have "thought" about $R$, although from your blog, you clearly have.

Comment: It is actually a very open question of determining whether two metrics are locally equivalent under a change of coordinates, largely because it involves a lot of PDEs. As @ACuriousMind suggests, you could take "Cartesian" Minkowski and write $t \rightarrow T(t,x,y,z)$, $x \rightarrow X(t,x,y,z)$, and so on, and write out the resulting metric in terms of the new variables $T,X,Y,Z$, which will still be flat necessarily. See this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9904070) by Mars for the Kerr case -- hopefully it will convince you the problem is highly non-trivial in general.

Comment: Actually -- you can probably use Simon's Theorem (Theorem 1 in the above paper) to answer this question (since he shows how one can check if a metric is isometric to Kerr, which has Minkowski as a limit where $M = a = 0$), though it won't tell you all of the possible ways to write such a metric it will give you a tool to check whether they are equivalent without directly using $R_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} = 0$. The calculation involved may actually be worse though. Interesting question.

Comment: @ArthurSuvorov I'm sure those comments would make a constructive  and worthwhile answer.

Answer (score 1):

A metric defines a flat space within an open neighborhood $U$ *if and only if* the Riemann tensor $R$ vanishes over that neighborhood. So you simply have to calculate $R$ and check that it vanishes in the neighborhood.

The *only if* part of the assertion is clear. The *if* part is probably more interesting to you and indeed a simple proof of the *if* shows you (in principle) how to construct the transformation to co-ordinates that will chart your whole neighborhood with Minkowski co-ordinates. Choose a point within your neighborhood $P$ and a basis $\{e_\mu\}$ for its tangent space. Now we simply use the fact that $R=0$ means that the parallel transport of a basis frame vanishes around a loop; otherwise put, the image under parallel transport of $\{e_\mu\}$ to any other point $Q$ in the neighborhood is independent of the path you tread to get there. So we simply compute this image (in principle) at every point in the neighborhood, and the results will be well defined. In this system, parallel transport of this basis between neighboring points yields the identity transformation, therefore the covariant derivatives $\{\nabla\,e_\mu\}$ all vanish everywhere; *a fortiori* so do all the commutators $[e_\mu,\,e_\nu]$ and so the vector fields defined by the $e_\mu$ can be integrated to co-ordinates wherein $e_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$, whence the connexion co-oefficients $\Gamma$ must all vanish too, that is, $x^\mu = a^\mu + b^\mu\,\lambda$ define geodesics in these co-ordinates, where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $\lambda$ the path parameter holds good over the whole neighborhood (i.e. it's not simply a local linearization approximating the tangent space to one point).

See Misner Thorne and Wheeler Section 11.5 for the finer details. Also, the present (16th June 2016) version of the Wikipedia article on the Riemann Curvature Tensor explains some of these points well; here's a particularly pithy little phrase from there that is good to remember:

> The curvature tensor measures noncommutativity of the covariant derivative, and as such is the integrability obstruction for the existence of an isometry with Euclidean space

although here, of course, one replaces Euclidean with Minkowskian. Most arguments about and properties of $R$ withstand the change from a Riemannian manifold (wherein the locally diagonalized metrics are nonsignatured) to a Lorentzian one (wherein the diagonalizations have the $(1,\,3)$ signature we all ken and love).